# How can I disable re-taking of pictures?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I use the built-in camera of the Iphone in my apps dans I have two questions.

```
UIImagePickerController *ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

ipc.delegate = self;

ipc.allowsEditing = NO;

[self presentModalViewController:ipc animated:YES];
```

First, my camera let the user use the picture he took or Retake, I want to take off this option, the user must have only one chance to take his picture.

Second, I want a change the title of the Cancel button on the left, because my app is in french.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "Cancel" button, I think you may try with internalization and localization. I don't know exactly how to do.

If you want to control the camera flow, it is harder than the normal way. You have to replace the default control buttons (in the bottom of the camera screen) with your own control. There are 2 methods that you need to do:

First, you need to set showCameraControls to NO: `picker.showCameraControls = NO`

`@property(nonatomic) BOOL showsCameraControls`

Then you need to supply your own view: picker.cameraOverlayView = YOUR_OWN_VIEW

`@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *cameraOverlayView`

Comment: The cancel button should be automatically localized; see CFBundleNativeDevelopmentRegion in Info.plist.

Comment: yeah, that's what I guess. Thanks for confirm